# How to avoid deadlock with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a CoreData stack that is like this:

```
Persistent Store -> (private)writingContext -> (main)UIContext
                 -> (private)backgroundContext
```

This is a commonly suggested stack to use in various blogs and people who have mastered CoreData, except that others will have the backgroundContext a child of the main context.  But thats not the issue I am seeing.  What I have is

```
[[self masterManagedObjectContext] performBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL saved = [self.masterManagedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (!saved) {
        // do some real error handling
        [EventLogger logError:@"CoreDataService" message:@"masterContext save ERROR" error:error];
    }
}];
```

Now this is executed from a UIContext performBlock calls this master save within a block and because its not blocking the next code to run is a tableView reload where it gets the fetched objects, accesses the properties and puts them on the tableViewCells.  I am getting a deadlock here because the save is still running but the UIContext is accessing the property values which are going into the master to pull the values into memory.  This happens consistently.

From what I understand, the contexts don't operate but on a single thread with a queue, well with the UI being a child of the master if the master is doing something and the child is requesting something at the same time, its causing the deadlock.  How do I avoid this?  How can I async save whats in the UI and not deadlock on accessing a property of an NSManagedObject?

Comment: Are you sure it is a deadlock?  from what you described I would expect it to be a write conflict.

Comment: From what I can debug it appears to be a deadlock, when it freezes I press pause in XCode and look at the threads.  Its stuck at saving the master context and accessing a property on a fetched object, which I can only assume its somehow faulted and trying to pull the data from the store while the store is being written to.  No other actions are being taken on any contexts or the store at the time but those.